# imgPreview: Preview the contents of a div

Tags: html, background

I would like to preview the content of a div with [imgPreview](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/)

I tried to do this:

```
<div id="five" style="background-image:url(1.jpg);"></div>
```

In script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div#five').imgPreview({
    containerID: 'imgPreviewWithStyles',
    imgCSS: {
        // Limit preview size:
        height: 200
    },
```

I would like that when it passes over muose make preview of 1.jpg

Help me!
 Many thanks, ando sorry for my bad english! :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ["imgPreview demos" @ james.padolsey.com](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/):

> The image preview shows up in a tooltip-like box appearing alongside
>   the user's cursor when hovering over a link. The plugin is entirely
>   unobtrusive; it does not require any hooks to target specific links
>   (no non-semantic classes); **it will automatically detect the anchors
>   that are linking to images and will only apply the preview effect to
>   them.**